# MySQL: newbie using SELECT and MAX

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `child` like this

```
+---------+-----+
| name    | age |
+---------+-----+
| Alfred  |   5 |
| Maria   |   6 |
+---------+-----+
```

When I run `SELECT 'name' FROM 'child'` I get both rows. No problem. It is what I expected.

But if I run `SELECT 'name', MAX('age') FROM 'child'` I get:

```
+---------+------------+
| name    | MAX(`age`) |
+---------+------------+
| Alfredo |          6 |
+---------+------------+
```

This result is extrange for me.. I expected both rows like before, why it is outputting just one row? why `Alfredo` is outputted since Maria is who is 6 years old? where can I find *documentation* about this behaviour?

Comment: MySQL behaviour is misleading, he doesn't deserve downvotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP BY` to get more than one row. Otherwise the aggregate function `MAX()` is applied on all rows. Notice, that Alfredo's age is actually 5. The name is the group in this case.

MySQL is kind of special here, since it doesn't follow ANSI-Standard SQL. Usually **an error is thrown, when you don't specify a column from the `select` clause in the `group by` clause or apply an aggregate function on it.** MySQL allows this (this will be changed in future versions, btw) and displays a **random row** from this group. So don't do this.

To get two rows in your example, you'd have to do

```
SELECT name, MAX(age) FROM your_table GROUP BY name;
```

Each name is a "group". If you would have another Alfredo with age 25 in your table, the result would be Alfredo - 25 and Maria - 6.

It gets more complicated than this when you want to get the row which belongs to the group-wise maximum. [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//example-maximum-column-group-row.html) are some examples how to solve this.

[More info to read](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).

To be on the safe side, you can disable this by setting the sql_mode [`only_full_group_by`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by). Ask your administrator if you don't have the rights to do so.

Comment: thanks, now I get two rows, but where is the reference to the maximum age? How to retrieve the maximum age? This is what I get now: `+---------+------------+
| name    | MAX(`age`) |
+---------+------------+
| Alfredo |          5 |
| Maria   |          6 |
+---------+------------+
`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Each name is a "group". If you would have another Alfredo with age 25 in your table, the result would be Alfredo - 25 and Maria - 6.

Comment: It gets more complicated than this when you want to get the row which belongs to the group-wise maximum. [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//example-maximum-column-group-row.html) are some examples how to solve this. @ziiweb Edited my answer to include this information.

Answer (score 0):

Use of SQL aggregate functions should be accompanied by a GROUP BY clause.  Here's a good place to start: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

You should SQL aggregate functions like Average, Max, etc with group by sql statements only. Otherwise you will get undefined behaviours like this one.

Here if you write `max(age)` only, everything looks good and you get 6, but now you also ask it to print the name(with no condition, i.e. asking it to print all names while max will only be one row), so it tries to do something intelligent and printing the first row is what it does in your case.

Answer (score 0):

`MAX()` is an [aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) to be used with `GROUP BY`. When the `GROUP BY` clause is missing, any `RDBMS` will produce a single group from all the selected rows and it will return a single row.

When grouping is involved, the expressions that appear in the `SELECT` clause are evaluated independently. There is no relationship between `name` and `MAX(age)`. `MAX(age)` is the maximum value of column `age` from the rows filtered by the `WHERE` clause (all the rows in your case).

The standard `SQL` language does not allow `SELECT`ing columns that are not dependent on the `GROUP BY` columns or used in aggregate functions.
MySQL allows this [before version 5.7.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html). Starting with version 5.7.5 it adheres to the standard and rejects such queries with errors. The old behaviour can still be achieved using configuration.

As explained in the documentation, for `SELECT` columns that are neither dependent on the `GROUP BY` columns nor used in aggregate functions, [*"the server is free to choose any value from each group"*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html). This is **undefined behaviour**.

Back to your query:

```
SELECT 'name', MAX('age') FROM 'child'
```

It has no `WHERE` all the rows are included. Then, because of `MAX(age)` (which is an aggregate function), MySQL creates a group that contains all the filtered rows (all the rows) and evaluates each of the expressions from the `SELECT` clause.

`MAX(age)` is very clear, it evaluates to the maximum value found the column `age` of the rows from the group. That is `6` and nothing more. No reference to the row where it was extracted from is kept.

Selecting a `name` is affected by the undefined behaviour exposed above. The server will select any value and, this time, it seems it preferred to pick the value from the first row. It could be different on another server. It could be different on the same server after you add, remove or update a row on that table. It just cannot be predicted.

#### Why this behaviour?

*Why the server doesn't get the value from **the same row** where it got the value of `MAX(age)`? Is it that difficult to accomplish?* -- This is how a lot of beginners think when they start working with `SQL`.

The short answer is: because **there is no such row**.

Let's say `SQL` should select `name` from the same row it selected `MAX('age')`.
Let's put more [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) in the query:

```
SELECT 'name', MAX('age'), MIN('age'), AVG('age'), COUNT(*) FROM 'child'
```

If the above assertion would be correct, `SQL` should get `name` from the same row that contains `MAX(age)` (row #2). What if there are two rows containing that value?

But, on the same time it should get `name` from the same row that contains `MIN(age)` (ahem, this is row #1).

Or, it should get it from the row where is finds `AVG(age)` (which is `5.5`; oops, there is no such row).

What about the row that contains `COUNT(*)` in column... errr... in what column should it check for `COUNT(*)`? Btw, `COUNT(*)` is not an age or a name, it is just a number. It doesn't make any sense to compare it with values you store in the table.